# Is there a way to count how many strings in a specific column are seen for the 1st time?

Tags: sql

**Is there a way to count how many strings in a specific column are seen for

Since the value in the column 2 gets repeated sometimes due to the fact that some clients make several transactions in different times (the client can make a transaction in the 1st month then later in the next year).
Is there a way for me to count how many IDs are completely new per month through a group by (never seen before)?

Please let me know if you need more context.
Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is two levels of aggregation.  The inner level gets the first date for each customer.  The outer summarizes by year and month:

```
select year(min_date), month(min_date), count(*) as num_firsts
from (select customerid, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by customerid
     ) c
group by year(min_date), month(min_date)
order by year(min_date), month(min_date);
```

Note that date/time functions depends on the database you are using, so the syntax for getting the year/month from the date may differ in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should generate associate every ID with year and month which are completely new then count, while grouping by year and month:

```
SELECT count(*) as new_customers, extract(year from t1.date) as year, 
extract(month from t1.date) as month FROM table t1 
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t1.id==t2.id AND t2.date<t1.date) 
GROUP BY year, month;
```

Your results will contain, new customer count, year and month

Comment: Thank you very much! What if I would like to receive the results of how many are completely new to the column by month grouping by date? It would change the structure, right?

Comment: @mcksoulnuke If there are no records before period, then they are completely new, aren't they?

Comment: Indeed! Could you please see the new edit part of the post? Thank you very much! I value your effort!

Comment: @mcksoulnuke I cannot fully understand what you want, do you want to count completely new customers for every day in a months?

Comment: completely new customers throughout the whole history of the column, grouped by months as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following which will assign a rank to each of the transactions which are unique for that particular customer_id (rank 1 therefore will mean that it is the first order for that customer_id)

The above is included in an inline view and the inline view is then queried to give you the month and the count of the customer id for that month ONLY if their rank = 1.

I have tested on Oracle and works as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_transaction) AS month,
    COUNT(customer_id)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            date_of_transaction,
            customer_id,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id
                ORDER BY
                    date_of_transaction ASC
            ) AS rank
        FROM
            table_1
    )
WHERE
    rank = 1
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_transaction)
ORDER BY 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_transaction) ASC;
```